# Excel - SUMIFS: changing sign of summed elements based on criteria

Tags: excel

[image]

I need to implement the following formula to get the desired result ($32.000 instead of $96.000) - as from cell C3 (see picture)

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Assets",INDEX(F:F,MATCH(B3,G:G,0)))),1,-1)*SUMIFS(H:H,G:G,B3)
```

The issue is that the formula sets the sign (+ or -) for the whole formula based on the first parameter it founds ("+" for "Assets" ; "-" for "Liabilities") when it should treat them independently and sum them accordingly.

I've managed to get the result using the "Account"'s parameters (besides the "Ledger Account"'s) as external criteria, but that's something I'd like to avoid.

```
=SUMIFS($G:$G;$F:$F;B3;$E:$E;E3)-SUMIFS($G:$G;$F:$F;B3;$E:$E;E4)
```

Comment: You could use `SUMIF` with a wildcard `*` and the text "Assets" and "Liabilities" - and subtract the difference.

Comment: The bigger question - is why is a ledger account used for *both* assets and liabilities (but I'm sure that is not something you can fix).

Comment: The *only* distinguishing characteristics are the "Account" parameters in column E - so you *can't* avoid using them in some form, based on the screenshot you've provided.

Comment: During the fiscal year credit notes use the same ledger account both for payables and receivables

Comment: Sumif + wildcard * works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've got something that works with that second formula. Stringing together a few sumifs is a simple way of solving this:

`=SUMIFS(G:G,F:F,B3,E:E,"*assets")+SUMIFS(G:G,F:F,B3,E:E,"*revenues")-SUMIFS(G:G,F:F,B3,E:E,"*liabilities")-SUMIFS(G:G,F:F,B3,E:E,"*costs")`